# make custom window chrome with wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, window-chrome

(this is a Q&A style question, I've answered it myself already)

"
I'm making a custom window chrome in wpf
but when I set it to windowStyle=none it

- clips out of the window
- I cant drag the window
- and the window covers the taskbar

"

Answer (score -1):

**solving problem 1**

make the main grid in the window accessible by name:

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
```

then add these functions to create a margin when the window's state is changed

```
void setWinMargin()
{
    switch (WindowState)
    {
        case WindowState.Maximized:
            MainGrid.Margin = new Thickness(8, 8, 8, 8);
            break;
        case WindowState.Normal:
            MainGrid.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
}

private void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setWinMargin();
}
```

and this to you're xaml in your

> StateChanged="Window_StateChanged"

what this will do is push everything away from the edges of the screen to be visible

**solving problem 2**

inside your window:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="35">
    </WindowChrome>
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

make CaptionHeight your window chrome's height, where you want the window to be dragged *by*

**solving problem 3**

don't use windowstate none, just define the windowchrome and the origional will be gone
the buttons (on the right hand side) will still be there, just invisible, so you will have to put buttons over them